# Write custom boot loader to .vhd file

Tags: c, bootloader, vhd

I have a custom boot loader that I would like to write to a .VHD file for testing. Any idea at what offset in the file I should write the boot loader to? Any pointers to the C structures for the .VHD file format?

Answer (score -1):

The specifications for the vhd file format are available [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualserver/bb676673.aspx).

You would probably have to read through the specs to find the details to do what you want.